# meaning of pythonic code s[::-1]

Tags: python

I tested the following python code which reverses a string

```
>> s = 'abcd'
>> s[::-1]
>> 'dcba'
```

But I am confused, what exactly the two comma and negative one does it the code ?

Comment: A great description is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

read up on list slicing.
This is the same question asked by another user.
[Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)